# How to design cover page/template for infographic?

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, print-design, information-graphics, template-design

I want to design a cover page for my analytical report, which contains 6-7 charts + information. So, I need advanced/professional software in order to design text, font size/design, place charts .... So, which software could you recommend? Or even an R package?

Comment: .. well.. you tagged this with InDesign.. so why not that???

Comment: Free software perhaps? Scribus (page layout like InDesign), Inkscape (vector software like Illustrator).